# How to mole SharePointServiceLocator to work with the logger

Tags: moles, pex-and-moles

I trying to figure out how to mole the

```
Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common.ServiceLocation.SharePointServiceLocator.GetCurrentFarmLocator
```

because I trying to use

```
 Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common.Logging.SharePointLogger.WriteToDeveloperTrace
```

some help or example?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by myself using the SharePointServiceLocator.
Basically I implemented this on my code:

```
            var replaceLocator = new ActivatingServiceLocator ( );
            SharePointServiceLocator.ReplaceCurrentServiceLocator ( replaceLocator );
            replaceLocator.RegisterTypeMapping < ILogger, MockLogger > ( InstantiationType.AsSingleton );
            replaceLocator.RegisterTypeMapping < ITraceLogger, MockLogger > ( InstantiationType.AsSingleton );
            replaceLocator.RegisterTypeMapping < IEventLogLogger, MockLogger > ( InstantiationType.AsSingleton );
```